# Combine 2 elastic search queries

Tags: database, elasticsearch, lucene

I've 2 `function_score` queries.

The first one, that I run on `attractions` type

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "translations",
          "query": {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "Text to search",
              "type": "best_fields",
              "fields": [
                "title^3",
                "description"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "cityId": 3
            }
          },
          "weight": 100
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

and the second one, that I run on `pizzeria` type

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "Text to search",
          "type": "best_fields",
          "fields": [
            "name^3",
            "description"
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "cityId": 1
            }
          },
          "weight": 100
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

They both works well. I know want to search on both types with a single query but I don't know how to "merge" these 2 queries.

I want to do this because I want to have the elements from the 2 type sorted by the same score.

Is this possible ? How Can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Multi Search API to combine queries into one single query:

[Multi Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)

Comment: This is not what I want. I want search on 2 indexes and get results sorted by score.